# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't detect my notebook touchscreen

Tags: laptop, touchscreen, ubuntu-drivers

ubuntu 18.04 doesn't detect the touchscreen on HKC Y11CC notebook. I have tried `xinput` and `xinput-calibrator` and most of them try to search for an external touchscreen interface. I want to test an inbuilt touchscreen. thank you